# Where to store Column Master Key for Always Encryption

Tags: sql-server-2016

We are going to use Always Encryption on few of the columns in our database tables. I gone through some of the articles on this subject and stuck on two points.

1. Say I am going to use same server for my database and my web application. Now I can save the Column Master Key(CMK) in the Windows certificate store of the current machine. How can I ensure that except Administrator no other database user can access the plain text data from SSMS?
2. I have separate servers for database and web application. In the time of encryption, the CMK certificate get created in the database server. Now I can  export the certificate and install it in web application server. Can I remove the certificate from the database server so that nobody can see the plain text data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Re #2, there is no need to generate the key on the database server. The best practice is to do that remotely so you don't accidently forget to remove it.

Comment: This should probably be on DBA, not SO, as it doesn't seem to be about programming.